# How to install lxml into virtualenv from the local system?

Tags: python, virtualenv

There is lxml module installed on my system (debian package `python-lxml`, for python 2.6), also I'm using virtualenv based on python2.6, installed with flag `--no-site-packages`.

Is it possible to install lxml inside virtual environment without compilation using some standard tools (pip, easy_install etc) and already install lxml binary files from the base system?

P.S.
I can, of course, manually create symlinks/copy files but don't like this method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may create required symlinks automatically by [bootstrap script](http://www.virtualenv.org/en/latest/index.html#bootstrap-example).