# Pip recognize linked site-packages in virtualenv

Tags: python, virtualenv, pip

For a number of reasons, such as when the package takes a long time to compile (lxml) it seems to be recommended to symlink such packages from the system sitepackages directory to a virtualenv.

Some example questions:

[Use a single site package (as exception) for a virtualenv](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13703074/708221)

[How to install lxml into virtualenv from the local system?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7117361/708221)

But such packages are not recognized by pip, which will happily try to reinstall them. How to deal with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, it seems the trick is to also link the egg-info directory.